# Finding the longest string in an array of Strings

Tags: java, java-stream

The problem with this is that i tried to do it but my method to check the length of the string is not working; what can I do to fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String[] animalNames = {"cat", "rabbit", "horse", "goat", "rooster", "ooooooooooooooo"};
    String a= getLongestString(animalNames);
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static String getLongestString(String []animalNames) {
  //  String animalNames[] =  {"cat","chicken","horse","ooooooooo" };

    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <= animalNames.length; j++) {
        if (animalNames[j].length() > animalNames[j + 1].length()) {
                return (animalNames[j]);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are only returning the one longer than the next, which surely should throw an error when you encounter the last. (**0. Properly format your post!**) 1. Store the length and index of the first string. 2. Update both when you find a longer string. 3. Return the string from the longest index.

Comment: What happens if there are several strings with a length of 10 and they are all the longest? If this is C# the following works `animalNames.Aggregate("", (max, cur) => max.Length > cur.Length ? max : cur);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here.
 1. You use `j<= animalNames.length;`?

2. You compare `animalNames[j + 1]`? -> error index out of array
3. and you return in the first if condition `return (animalNames[j]);` -> wrong value

Ok, let me make clear.
You find the longest string in an array. You loop over the array then you compare 2 near elements, and then return the bigger one.
With your code, it will return the rabbit. Right?

May be you confuse about the process flow.
There is a simple way.

1. You assign a variable for the length of the first array element: elementLength = array[0].length; and a value to keep track of the index
2. You loop over the array
   You check every element with this variable, if bigger then re-assign the element value and update the index.
3. End of the loop. you have the biggest length and the index

Code:

```
int index = 0; 
int elementLength = array[0].length();
for(int i=1; i< array.length(); i++) {
    if(array[i].length() > elementLength) {
        index = i; elementLength = array[i].length();
    }
}
return array[index];
```

that is it.

Answer (score 22):

It's real simple using java 8+ (just check that your array is not empty first or process the `.get()` specially):

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(animals);    
String longest = strings.stream().
    max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get();
int max = longest.length();
```

OR, if you just need the length:

```
int max = strings.stream().map(String::length).max(Integer::compareTo).get();
```

Or, if you prefer a one-liner, it's:

```
String longest = Arrays.asList(animals)
     .strings.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get();
=AND= 
int max = Arrays.asList(animals)
           .stream().map(String::length).max(Integer::compareTo).get();
```

Well, okay.. it's actually two-liner :-) Enjoy!

**UPDATE:**

Instead of  `Arrays.asList(animals).strings.stream()` one could use directly `Stream.of(animals)`

Comment: You're getting the length of the longest string, which is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

I think there should not be `array.length();` otherwise you'll be getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` because we cant use length() for array of string, instead we can use for particular string length.

Comment: What does this add to the question?  I believe that the previous responses already covered what you're saying here.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class LongestWord {
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the string for finding longest word");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc1.nextLine(), x=null;
        String str2[] = str.split(" ");

        x=str2[0];
        int i =0,j = 0;
        for( i = 0; i < str2.length; i = j)
        {
            for( j =i+1; j < str2.length; j++)
            {
                if(x.length() < str2[j].length())
                {
                    x = str2[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the longest string is: " + x + " and it's length is: " + x.length());

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to why this answer is useful.  Otherwise, you risk getting it flagged.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] names = {"Greg", "Aleksandra", "Martha", "Oliwka"};

        String wynik = findLongestName(names);
        System.out.println( wynik);
    }

    public static String findLongestName(String [] names){
        int size = names.length;
        String longestName = names[0];

        for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            if(names[i].length() > longestName.length()){
            longestName = names[i];
        }}

        return longestName;
    }
}
```

Comment: to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException in for loop I used length of that array,

Comment: This answer doesn't really provide what the poster needs, which is an explanation of what's wrong with their code and how to fix it. You need to include more than just a rewritten function to be helpful.