# Is it possible to combine streams?

Tags: java

I have this code, the task of which is to determine the words of the longest, I made through several streams. How to combine them?

```
List<String> maxLengthWords = ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(createSubtasks()).stream()
        .flatMap(maxLengthWord -> maxLengthWord.join().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

int longest = maxLengthWords.stream()
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .max()
        .orElse(-1);

return maxLengthWords.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.length() == longest)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your edit makes your question a little better, but what is your objective? Your code example doesn't make it clear exactly what you're after.

Comment: The obvious answer to your edited question appears to be [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-merge-streams).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the longest string in an array of Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725296/finding-the-longest-string-in-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: Has @Tom divined what you're looking for?  Note that the verbal description of your problem appears to be missing one or two words, which is why I mentally glossed over it and reverted to your question title.

Comment: I would collect the words into a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` directly with something like `.collect(groupingBy(String::length, TreeMap::new, toList()))`, where the last `Map.Entry` would then store the longest words.

Comment: I wanted to ask if it is possible to combine these streams into one long one

Comment: Do you have to use Streams?  How about `Collections.max(maxLengthWords, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))`?  Or, if you must use Streams, `maxLengthWords.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take all collection and connect them with `Stream.of(...)` fucntion.

I couldn't understand what do you want to combime from your code but you can combine streams in the following way:

```
Stream.of(collectionA.stream(),collectionB.stream())
```

Take a look on:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-

Comment: I would assume you combine two streams in order to have one stream with all the elements, not just with two objects of type Steam. Probably a more useful general example would be 
`Stream.of(a.stream(), b.stream()).flatMap(Function.identity())`